# Pull Twitter User ID Of User That RTs/ Favs Tweet Of Another User

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I'm attempting to build a twitter bot that will tweet to anyone that RTs or Favourites a tweet of another account.

Is it possible using the streaming API to monitor another accounts tweets and pull the User ID and then use that to tweet at them?

I've been able to pull in another users tweets and check if they've been RTd or Favourites however I'm having issues separating their tweets from tweets they've RTd.

Also I'm unsure if it's possible to pull out the user ID of someone that RTs or Favourites a tweet.

I'm using this on my own twitter account and I'm attempting this in [python](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter).